# Ansible vars file - handling items with varying attributes

Tags: ansible

I'm still a bit new to Ansible, but I haven't been able to find a good example of how to handle the following situation:

In my vars_file, I am being provided something like the following...

```
- users
  - name: user_a
    age: 18
    car: "Datsun"

  - name: user_b
    age: 20
    pens: 
      - "Zebra F-701"
      - "Bic"

  - name: user_c
    age: 99
    car: "Horse and Buggy"
    pens: 
      - "Quill"
      - "Fountain Pen"
```

My playbook task looks like this:

```
- name: add users
  user:
    name: "{{ name }}"
    age: "{{ age }}"
    car: "{{ car }}"
    pens: "{{ item.pens | join(',') }}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

So user_a doesn't have any pens and user_b doesn't have a car, and the playbook fails appropriately because a variable is referenced that doesn't exist.

In a perfect world, if the task doesn't find the "car" variable when adding user_b, it carries on to the list of pens without error and successfully adds the user. Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: An option would be to use the [default filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add empty default values:

```
- name: add users
  user:
    name: "{{ name }}"
    age: "{{ age }}"
    car: "{{ car | default('') }}"
    pens: "{{ item.pens | default('') | join(',') }}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use the [default filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables)

```
car: "{{ item.car | default(omit) }}"
```